# TSQL Select Data From Table Only If it contains Value in Column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Let's say I have 5 tables. Every table contains column "`INFERRED_MEMBER`", this is `bit` data type so it can have only `0` or `1` value assigned.

Now I want to `SELECT * FROM` only those tables which has any "`1`" in "`INFERRED_MEMBER`" column.

So the logic is like this:
If `TABLE1` contains `1` anywhere in the column "`INFERRED_MEMBER`", return

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE INFERRED_MEMBER = 1
```

and so on for rest of the tables.

How to achieve this? I assume "`CASE`" function is not built for this.

Comment: Can you not use `UNION` or `UNION ALL` for each table with the query you have shown?

Comment: The tables have different amount of columns. I imagine there could be something like IF ... THEN execute "SELECT * FROM ...".

Comment: @DNac you can join these tables based on column `INFERRED_MEMBER`  and you need only tables column in where clause .

Comment: If you want all the 5 tables on the same select you must select same metadata from all the queries to use UNION(if you want distinct values) or UNION ALL like Raj sugested. You can inject columns as NULL on some queries to get the same number of columns from the 5 selects

Comment: If the tables have different number of columns, how do you plan on selecting in one statement? Showing us an expected result involving at least two tables might help

Comment: OK, Ill try the both Majdi's solution and union with NULL injection as per comment. Ill come back once done, thanks for suggestions!

Comment: It works with UNION table with NULL injection, thanks for the idea. So simple I should have thought this myself.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want different result sets you can use (IF EXISTS) for each table like:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE INFERRED_MEMBER = 1)
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE INFERRED_MEMBER = 1
```

otherwise you should use UNION like mxix commented

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify the EXISTS statement can be in the WHERE clause ie:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE1 WHERE INFERRED_MEMBER = 1)

UNION ALL 

SELECT * 
FROM TABLE2 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE2 WHERE INFERRED_MEMBER = 1)
```

etc. There are nicer ways to do it and dyanamic alternatives that would identify the tables for you and run the output etc.